# Is there a way to do string manipulations on parameters in Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy

I'm looking to pass a substring of a parameter passed to a Jenkins Parameterized build to my build process, but not sure if/how to do this.  Specifically, I have a parameterized job in Jenkins that takes a branch name as a parameter.

I would like to pass a substring of the branch name to my build command - the type of branch.  For example, if my branch is a `feature/myBranch`, I want to extract the `feature` substring and pass that as a parameter to my build.

Is there an easy/simple way of doing this in Jenkins?  Can parameters be manipulated similar to Bash parameters? Or is my only way to use a Groovy Script accomplish what I would expect to be a straightforward task?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the "inject environment variable plugin"

first get the substring in "Execute windows batch command"

```
SET BOUGH=%branch:~8% # evaluates to 'myBranch'
echo BOUGH=%BOUGH% > propsfile.txt
```

then use the "Inject environment variables" plugin with properties file path set to propsfile.txt